# Is there a way to add custom attributes to OAuth2Authorizations in Spring's Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I'm using `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1` with the `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` to persist `OAuth2Authorization` instances to a database. I would like to include additional details about the request in the database. In particular I'm looking to capture the User-Agent HTTP header and the request's IP address.

Looking at `OAuth2Authorization` and `OAuth2Authorization.Builder`, [there's an attribute Map](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/OAuth2Authorization.Builder.html#attribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) that can be populated with extra details like this, but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate use the attributes feature, nor do I see a way to hook into spring-security to capture details from the `HttpServletRequest`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently a direct way to customize an `OAuth2Authorization` before it is saved. However, you can do this with delegation by implementing a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationService`. For example:

```java
@Component
public class DecoratingOAuth2AuthorizationService implements OAuth2AuthorizationService {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationService delegate;

    public DecoratingOAuth2AuthorizationService(
            JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate,
            RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        this.delegate = new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(OAuth2Authorization authorization) {
        OAuth2Authorization updatedAuthorization = OAuth2Authorization.from(authorization)
                // ... add attributes
                .build();
        this.delegate.save(updatedAuthorization);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Note:** The `HttpServletRequest` is available via `((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest()`.